# Cytoscape-expand-collapse graph hangs when i expand a top level coompound node

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I have a very basic cytoscape.js graph with cytoscape-expand-collapse.

There are two nodes with an edge between them. On top of one of those nodes, are two parent compound nodes.

When i collapse both the parents and they try to expand them again, the graph gets stuck(probably in an infinite loop somewhere).

[Here](https://codepen.io/utkarsh-agarwal/pen/ZPrbzq) is a codepen showing the problem.
And the code:

**BEWARE:** Your browser might get stuck if you try to expand the node.

```html
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
container: document.getElementById('cy'),
ready: function(){
  var api = this.expandCollapse({
    layoutBy: {
      name: "cose-bilkent",
      animate: true,
      ranker: 'network-simplex',
      fit: true,
      // nodeDimensionsIncludeLabels: true, 
    },
    fisheye: false,
    undoable: false,
  });
  api.collapseAll();
},
elements: {
  "nodes": [{
    "data": {
      "id": "tea-beverage",
      "label": "Tea Beverage",
      "parent": "NA-canary"
    }
  }, {
    "data": {
      "id": "frontend-hotdrinks",
      "label": "FrontEnd Hot Drinks",
      "parent": "frontend-canary"
    }
  }, {
    "data": {
      "id": "frontend",
      "label": "frontend",

    }
  },{
    "data": {
      "id": "frontend-canary",
      "label": "canary",
      "parent": "frontend",

    }
  }],
  "edges": [{
    "data": {
      "source": "frontend-hotdrinks",
      "target": "tea-beverage",
    }
  }],
}
});
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Of note: https://github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-expand-collapse/issues/69

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine with Cytoscape.js version <= 3.3.6

As usual, @maxkfranz keeps breaking backwards compatibility.

You can create a new issue [here](https://github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-expand-collapse/issues/new).

Comment: Will do it soon. Thanks for the answer here and on my other question too :)